# Where is the Bootstrap v4 Button Plugin?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, plugins, radio-button, bootstrap-4

The [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#button-plugin) refers to a "Button Plugin":

> ### Button plugin
>
> Do more with buttons. Control button states or create groups of buttons for more components like toolbars.

Where is it? I can't find any reference to it anywhere.

The particular thing I'm trying to do is get proper radio button behaviour across multiple button groups, which doesn't seem to work using the default button behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Button plugin" refers to a part of Bootstrap [JavaScript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js). So to enable these features, you just need to insert this snippet before `</body>`:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here's an example with styled radio buttons:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Radio 1 (preselected)
  </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio 2
  </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio 3
  </label>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, I'm still a bit confused about the "plugin" aspect. This doesn't match what is normally called a plugin - optional bits of functionality that are enabled with supplementary libraries. It sounds like this is core functionality?

Comment: Hello, I agree. "Plugin" doesn't sound right in this case, but **yes it is core functionality** of the Bootstrap JS. Nothing extra needded.